# character position ambiguity java

Tags: java, swing

I have an `JEditorPane` using `styledDocument`.

My problem is caused by newlines. Because I am making application for windows, newline is represented by (CR LF).

Problem is that `chartAt(int)` method on text extracted form editor kit counts newlines as two characters but `setCharacterAttributes(int, int, AttributeSet, boolean)` method on styledDocument counts newlines as one character.

So suppose I want to apply attribute set on all characters "福". Simple and intuitive:

```
String text; //set to text of JEditorPane
StyledDocument doc; //set to doc of JEditorPane 
int length = text.length();
for (int iii = 0; iii < length; iii++) {
    if (text.chartAt(iii) == '福')
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(iii, 1, AttributeSet, boolean);
}
```

It will work only until first newline. then it gets one char off, and one more char with each newline.

how can I work with consistent character position?

Comment: I suspect this could be because of dual byte characters rather than the behaviour of `StyledDocument` or `charAt`. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) for details on how charAt uses lower and upper surrogate characters (one byte in dual byte characters). One way to confirm that is to have only ascii characters in the `JEditorPane` and test code with a ascii character.

Comment: @Nivas - that was first i though off, but it was not the case. This is why i emphasized that it works "until first newline". Check accepted answer of DWilches for what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a document is read with `StyledDocument` it is kept in memory and the new-line characters are replaced by `'\n'`. Source: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html)

So you will have to take this into account and check what is the length of your new-line characters by using the [EndOfLineStringProperty property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html#EndOfLineStringProperty).

So whenever you see a `'\n'` in your text, you have to know if you have to count it as 1 or 2 chars actually.

Other solutions are:

- Change the `EndOfLineStringProperty` to `'\n'` after you have read your document, and then instruct `StyledDocument` to save the document to a String. Then in that String you can count the newlines as just one char, in the same way the `StyledDocument` is doing.
- Replace every occurrence of `EndOfLineStringProperty` to `'\n'` inside of `text` and then the count will work.

Answer (score 0):

> It will work only until first newline. then it gets one char off, and one more char with each newline.

This sounds like the same problem found with a JTextPane. Check out [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information.

The proposed solution is to use:

```
text.getDocument().getText();
```

instead of

```
text.getText();
```